# AngularJS - Need to clear javascript object on controller change

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new to AngularJs. Currently I have a directive that populates a JavaScript object called `keyListeners`. Now this object gets populated and serves its purpose fine the first time I come to the page on which it is used. Unfortunately when I navigate away from the page and then come back to it I see errors in my console like

> "angular.min.js:116 More than one amtAltKey found for key 'A' "

Then the functionality of the page starts to break.

I know I could theoretically check for the existence of the element in keyListeners, before adding it to the object. However, instead of doing that I would like to run some logic to clear out keyListeners on control change. My directive that actually populates keyListeners is below. How can I clear this out every time the controller/page changes.

```
app.directive("amtAltKey", function () {
    return {
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            var altKey = attrs.amtAltKey.toUpperCase();
            if(keyListeners[altKey] !== undefined) { throw 'More than one amtAltKey found for key \''+ altKey + '\''; }
            if (altKey === '') { throw "Alt Key value key must be given"; }
            var el = elem[0];
            if (!el.hasChildNodes()) { throw 'amtAltKey element must have child text'; }
            if(el.firstChild.nodeName !== '#text') { throw 'amtAltKey element\'s child must be text'; }
            var text = el.innerText;
            var textUpper = text.toUpperCase();
            var indexOfKey = textUpper.indexOf(altKey);
            if (indexOfKey === -1) { throw 'amtAltKey for \'' + altKey + '\' was not found in element\s text; ' + text; }
            var newText = text.replace(new RegExp(attrs.amtAltKey), '<u>' + attrs.amtAltKey + '</u>');
            el.innerHTML = newText;
            keyListeners[altKey] = el;
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is keyListeners currently a global?  If so, that's the problem.  It's not being garbage collected when the directive is blown up, when switching screens.  Just add do something like...

```
var keyListenteners = {};
```

...in your directive.

Or, better, move keyListeners in to their own service or factory and include it.  Something like:

```
angular.module("myApp").factory("keyListeners", function() {
    return {
      // your properties here
    };
});
```

This will act like a data singleton, kind of like your global, between your different controllers.  A change made to one will be reflected in the others.  That of course is the very problem you want to avoid, so you could add a `clear()` method to this singleton and call it every time your route changes or even in your controller constructor.

Comment: In terms of adding it to the directive, I believe the problem there is that  this runs on each element that I have marked with an amt-alt-key attribute. Each one of these I want added to keyListeners{}. So I can't clear it at the beginning of the directive. --Jason

Comment: OK.  Then you want to share a service or factory between them (2nd example above).  The items added to this will live on even after the directive goes away, so you'll be able to clear or persist it however you like in response to your routers.